# Conditional density for random effects prediction in GLMM

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian-probability, expectation

I am currently working on generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) and need some help concerning the prediction of the random effects. More specifically, I don't understand the given representation of the conditional expectation of the random effect, i.e.
$$ \mathbb{E}[X | Y] = \int  f_{X|Y} (x|y)\: dx = \int \frac{f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)}{\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)dx} dx$$(the second equation being the one I don't understand)

This is the representation in general. In a one way classification, $X$ would be the random effect, $Y$ the response group (vector) for the random effect.
Found in several papers and books of McCulloch et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with GLMM's per se. All what is done here is using the definition 
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x):=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$
(if $f_X(x)\ne0$) to write 
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)=f_{X,Y}(x,y),$$
so that
$$\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)\,dx=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx=f_Y(y)$$
and hence 
$$\frac{f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)}{\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)\,dx}
=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
=f_{X|Y} (x|y).$$

Comment: I know it does not, nevertheless I wanted to give some context to the question. Thank you for the derivation!